# Can someone explain the phrase "order-preserving permutation of a totally ordered set"?

Tags: order-theory

If a set is totally ordered, then any nontrivial permutation would destroy that order, so I'm clearly missing something.

I have seen this exact phrase in many papers and books, mostly those dealing with ordered groups.

Comment: You're right that arbitrary permutations might destroy the order. It's not true for *every* permutation of *every* totally ordered set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not true that any nontrivial permutation destroys a total ordering. This is true for finite sets, but "most" infinite sets are counter examples. For example, $x\to x+1$ preserves the total order on the integers, rationals, and reals.

Another example is to take $\mathbb{Q}$ and double every number bigger than $0$, and leave the rest fixed.

Just these two will let you produce many, as the composition of order preserving permutations is an order preserving permutation.

Comment: I'll file this one under "duh".  Clearly, I was thinking only of finite sets.  Thanks.

Comment: A good, but very hard, problem is to characterize exactly those total orders which have no nontrivial order-preserving permutations. It's easy to show that *finite* orders have this property; also, *well-orders* (= total orders with no infinite descending sequence) and *co-well-orders* (= reversed well-orders); but also more annoying things like the order-type corresponding to the set of reals $\{1-{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{1+{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ ordered in the usual way (this order is usually called "$\omega+\omega^*$).